# OpenSSL for WinCE x86 and "error: can not open input file coredll.lib"

Tags: openssl, windows-ce

I am trying to build Compact-master for WinCE 7 x86 for OpenSSL.

In Visual Studio 2008 command prompt I added the following path:

```
set LIB = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\WinCE_7_x86\Lib\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib;D:\VISUAL STUDIO 2008\VS2008\VC\ce\lib\x86;D:\VISUAL STUDIO 2008\VS2008\VC\lib;

set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\WinCE_7_x86\Include\X86; set OSVERSION=WCE700 set PLATFORM=VC-CE set TARGETCPU=x86 set Path=D:\VISUAL STUDIO 2008\VS2008\Common7\IDE;D:\VISUAL STUDIO 2008\VS2008\VC\bin;%Path%

set LIBPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE Tools\SDKs\WinCE_7_x86\Lib\x86";D:\VISUAL STUDIO 2008\VS2008\VC\lib;
```

But while doing `nmake -f makefile` it gives the error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'coredll.lib'
```